# How reverse words in string and keep punctuation marks and upper case symbol

Tags: string, scala, reverse

```
private def reverseHelper(word: String): String = {
  var result = new StringBuilder(word)
  if (word.head.isUpper) {
    result.setCharAt(0, word.head.toLower)
    result.setCharAt(word.length - 1, word.last.toUpper)
  }
  result.reverse.result()
}
```

```
val formatString = str
  .split("[.,!?: ]+")
  .map(result => str.replaceFirst(result, reverseHelper(result)))
  .foreach(println)
```

Example:
Input: **What is a sentence?**
Ouput: **Tahw si a ecnetnes?**

but i have Array[String]: Tahw is a sentence?, What si a sentence?, What is a sentence?, What is a ecnetnes?
How i can write this in right format?

Comment: Please clarify: how should a `"CamelCase"` word be reversed? Should it be `"EsaClemac"` (all internal letters retain their original case), or should it be `"EsaclEmac"` (index positions retain their original case), or something else?

Comment: @jwvh EscaclEmac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version using `split` on word boundaries:

```
def reverseWords(string: String): String = {
  def revCap(s: String): String =
    s.headOption match {
      case Some(c) if c.isUpper =>
        (c.toLower +: s.drop(1)).reverse.capitalize
      case Some(c) if c.isLower =>
        s.reverse
      case _ => s
    }

  string
    .split("\\b")
    .map(revCap)
    .mkString("")
}
```

Comment: Won't preserve internal capitalization, e.g. "McMaster".

Comment: @jwvh It converts "McMaster" to "RetsaMcm", which matches the question. What do you think it should do?

Answer (score 1):

You can first split your string at a list of special characters and then reverse each individual word and store it in a temporary string. After that traverse the original string and temporary string and replace word matching any special characters with current character in temporary string.

```
private def reverseHelper(word: String): String = {
  var result = new StringBuilder(word)
  if (word.head.isUpper) {
    result.setCharAt(0, word.head.toLower)
    result.setCharAt(word.length - 1, word.last.toUpper)
  }
  result.reverse.result()
}

val tempStr = str
  .split("[.,!?: ]+")
  .map(result => reverseHelper(result))
  .mkString("")

val sList = "[.,!?: ]+".toList

var curr = 0

val formatString = str.map(c => {
          if(!sList.contains(c)) {
              curr = curr + 1
              tempStr(curr-1)
          }
          else c
      })
```

Comment: Where is `curr`? And what about other punctuation characters?

Comment: @Tim added it to the code. It is just a counter I am using to loop over the string to keep track of the index of `tempStr`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that uses a Regex pattern to generate a list of paired strings of `Seq(word, nonWord)`, followed by reversal and positional uppercasing of the `word` strings:

```
def reverseWords(s: String): String = {
  val pattern = """(\w+)(\W*)""".r

  pattern.findAllMatchIn(s).flatMap(_.subgroups).grouped(2).
    map{ case Seq(word, nonWord) =>
      val caseList = word.map(_.isUpper)
      val newWord = (word.reverse zip caseList).map{
          case (c, true)  => c.toUpper
          case (c, false) => c.toLower
        }.mkString
      newWord + nonWord
    }.
    mkString
}

reverseWords("He likes McDonald's burgers. I prefer In-and-Out's.")
//res1: String = "Eh sekil DlAnodcm's sregrub. I referp Ni-dna-Tuo's."
```

Comment: You'll get better preservation of between-word characters if you use `\W*` instead of `\W?`.

Comment: This does not match the captialization behaviour of the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

Restoring the original capitalization is a bit tricky.

```
def reverser(s:Seq[Char], idx:Int = 0) :String = {
  val strt = s.indexWhere(_.isLetter, idx)
  if (strt < 0) s.mkString
  else {
    val end = s.indexWhere(!_.isLetter, strt)
    val len = end - strt
    val rev = Range(0,len).map{ x =>
      if (s(strt+x).isUpper) s(end-1-x).toUpper
      else                   s(end-1-x).toLower
    }
    reverser(s.patch(strt,rev,len), end)
  }
}
```

testing:

```
reverser(       "What, is A sEntence?")
//res0: String = Tahw, si A eCnetnes?
```

Comment: That is not what the original code does. The original code just transfers the capitalization of the first letter to the last letter.

Comment: @Tim; Hmm, the question isn't completely clear on this. Hopefully the OP will chime in.